# Android: Creating custom support v7 preference not working as Expected

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-custom-view, android-preferences, android-preference-v14

I have created a sample demo application for the custom Android preference using `support library preference-v7`.

**Code:** https://github.com/saurabhkpatel/Android-Custom-Preference-Sample

I am facing two problems here:

1. In this demo application, I have total three different types of preferences. One is `ListPreference`, Second is `Custom Preference` which I have created and the last one is `SwitchPreferenceCompat`. If I put `Custom Preference` in between these two preferences categories then it's not working expected. Please check this attached screenshot. You can see that third `SwitchPreferenceCompat` is missing.
2. Even I can see the seek bar twice which comes from custom layout file, but I have only one seek-bar over there.

Everything is working fine if I put `SampleCustomPreference` at last.

Any ideas, Why this behavior is happening?

Thanks for your time.

**UnExpected**
[image]

**Expected**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The layout file layout_pref.xml has an issue. The height of the parent layout should be wrap content not match parent. Corrected xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.SearchResult.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="C Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/summary"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.SearchResult.Subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="C Summary" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```